# How to hide the status bar programmatically in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, hide, statusbar, ios6.1

In [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7), how can I hide the [statusbar](/questions/tagged/statusbar) programmatically? I am using `XCode 4.6.1` ([ios6.1](/questions/tagged/ios6.1)) and I want to implement this in XCode itself.

Answer (score 72):

in iOS7 you should implement in your viewController

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 33):

you can hide status bar to set the key value "View controller-based status bar appearance" NO in plist. This is easiest way.

or You can hide in code by using property statusBarHidden of UIApplication class.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

**Swift 3.0**

Hide status bar for any particular view controller

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

Hide Status bas across the application

UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

and set the key value "View controller-based status bar appearance" NO in info plist of project.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 7. The correct answer is by @user2826529

Comment: Works for me. Ensure you set the property he mentions in the plist appropriately.

Comment: Far the best solution. Forget all the stuff above. Apple made it way too complicated.

Comment: Override code works perfectly in iOS 13, Xcode 11.3, Swift 5.  UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden is deprecated.

Answer (score 18):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
}

// Add this method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me. I have used this same but the status bar always shown. Please help..

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide]; This will work and there is a property in info.plist where you can hide the status bar.

Comment: After hiding the statusbar, how can it be shown again? Because I want to alter the statusbar visible status programmatically.

Comment: There is no need to perform the selector.

Comment: @AndrasHatvani The question specified using Xcode 4, which means that he doesn't have the iOS 7 API. He uses performSelector to avoid "no method found" warning.

Comment: @echo See my answer if you still need to do this.

Answer (score 5):

To hide for a specific ViewController (and then turn back on) when `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `NO`:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to hide/show it on a given view controller dynamically you can do something like this.

(Although I recommend just using `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` to return your preference if you don't need it to change.)

```
// view controller header 
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController  {
    BOOL shouldHideStatusBar;
}
@end


@implementation

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return shouldHideStatusBar; // backed by your instance variable
}

- (void)setPrefersStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    shouldHideStatusBar = hidden;

    // Don't call this on iOS 6 or it will crash since the 
    // `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method doesn't exist
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];

    // [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]; // (if Xcode 5, use this)
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of iOS >= 7.0 use following code :

Syntax:

```
// Present in UIViewController of UIKit Frameworks
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // Defaults to NO
```

Usage:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

---

In iOS < 7.0 use following code :

Syntax:

```
// Present in UIApplication of UIKit Frameworks
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2);
```

Usage:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4.1

**step1.** Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your `info.plist` to **YES**

**step2.** Type some code in your `UIViewController`, status bar will hide when you present the `UIViewController`.

```
private var statusBarIsHidden = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    statusBarIsHidden = true
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return statusBarStatus
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wanted the most updated way to do it (Swift 2.1 and latest Xcode 7.2)

1. Set "View controller based status bar appearance to NO in your info.plist"
2. UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true // put inside app delegate somewhere (applicationWill or DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that you need both the code and the value in the info.plist file in iOS 9 / Xcode 7.3.

Add this to your **viewDidLoad** method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Add this to your info.plist file as a boolean value and set it to NO:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance
```

Answer (score 0):

If using iOS 9.0+ and Swift. If you want to have status bar hidden in some view controllers but not all - make sure to have `View controller-based status bar appearance` value in `Info.plist` set to `YES` else same parameters will be used across all view controllers.

And override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in subclass of `UIViewController`

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

Similar can be done to change `preferredStatusBarStyle`

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    get {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on swift 4:

```
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = ..true/false
```

Comment: Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]