# Toggle iOS 7 Status bar with an UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uistatusbar

I'm trying to use an UISwitch to toggle the status bar (Xcode 5, iOS 7). I currently have this code

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

This hides the status bar completely. but I want to both hide and show the status bar with an UISwitch or with a button click. How can I do it ?

I think returning a boolean value (YES or NO) to prefrersStatusBarHidden will do the job. But I couldn't find any guide about returning values to BOOL.

Answer (score 2):

Have your `prefersStatusBarHidden` return a property of your object, such as `self.hideStatusBar`, then in your method for the button/switch do:

```
// Set self.hideStatusBar value based on what the user did
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
{
    // iOS 7+
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
else
{
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:self.hideStatusBar withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

The above code is from [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19074994/657676)

Make sure to give `self.hideStatusBar` a default value!

Comment: Thanks..However it didn't work. but I went through the link you gave and found the method as another answer !

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

in .h file header

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

BOOL shouldHideStatusBar;
```

code

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return shouldHideStatusBar;
}

- (void)setPrefersStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    shouldHideStatusBar = hidden;

    //[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 animations:^{ //this animates the event
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }];
}
```

call it (in my case using an UISwitch)

```
[self setPrefersStatusBarHidden:NO];
```