# Dynamically hiding status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I want to hide the status bar at the click of a button. I have tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

I have had no luck with this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067899/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-programmatically-in-ios-7

Comment: Yeah I was just hoping there was another way.

Comment: Check out this answer for a way to make it change when you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18856079/772156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is, go to the info.plist file. add row, "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set to NO. Check as an answer

Answer (score 2):

For toggling on and off in code only:

```
-(void)statusBarShouldHide:(bool)hide{

    hideStatusBar = hide;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
}
-(bool)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return hideStatusBar;
}
```

called by:

```
[self statusBarShouldHide:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do this programmingly 
try this.

override the funtion

```
-(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return needHideStatusBar;
}

-(IBAction) checkStatus {

    // do your judgment here 

    needHideStatusBar = YES;
    if ([self 
        respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
}
```