# How to set a UINavigation size to fit the background image size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've set my `UINavigationBar` background image to some image, like this:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menubar.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but I cant really see the whole image since its bigger than the default size on a UINavigationBar.

So two things please:

1. How to set a `UINavigation` size to fit the background image size?
2. I dont want to see the battery and time bar in the background, so my image will cover it.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not possible to set UINavigation size (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894985/change-uinavigationbar-height)), you have to fit the background image instead
2. It's impossible to cover the status bar, but you can easily hide it. See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067899/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-programmatically-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily remove status bar using info.plist file

just addRow and write "Status bar is initially hidden" and set value "YES"

end check to navigationBar
[iOS. How to change UINavigationBar height and change frames of the others subviews at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267349/ios-how-to-change-uinavigationbar-height-and-change-frames-of-the-others-subvie)