# How to hide status bar of a single view controller in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift

In a ViewController, which I presented modally, I did this:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This used to work, but it no longer works. What's the best way to hide the status bar **only** for this view controller?

Comment: just check Programtically way [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19067899/3388012)

Comment: It's still working fine. If you want to apply the function to all of your View Controllers then consider using inheritance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a status bar in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661031/how-to-hide-a-status-bar-in-ios)

Comment: Just go to info.plist and update **View controller-based status bar appearance** to **YES** as mentioned by @lance

Answer (score 70):

For **Swift 3** & **Swift 4** it has changed to overriding a variable like this:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return true
}
```

If you want to "Update" the state once the view controller is already being displayed, you will need to call:

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden).

Comment: in tabbarcontroller setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() not make prefersStatusBarHidden triggered

Comment: @famfamfam Make sure you don't have controller-based status bar appearance disabled in your info.plist. If you do this property is completely ignored. Also, PrefersStatusBarHidden might be getting called in a parent controller instead. It depends on how you organized your view controllers.

Answer (score 47):

For **Swift 3 and Swift 4.2**
when view going to Appear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}
```

when view goint to Dissapear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
```

It's possible you need set in your info.plist, next line:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

[image]

Comment: I believe it works since you messed up the ViewController hierarchy and system  don't call for prefersStatusBarHidden.

Comment: This is the only way I could do it but I also had to add <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <false/> to my info.plist file

Comment: `isStatusBarHidden` was deprecated in iOS 9.0

Answer (score 21):

In your UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    //It will show the status bar again after dismiss
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]

Answer (score 19):

In iOS 9, Xcode 7, Swift 2.0, it's back to how it was previously.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

In fact Xcode will tell you that

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
```

has been deprecated and that you should use the prefersStatusBarHidden method.

Comment: If the prefersStatusBarHidden method does nothing, add setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() to your viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method. Depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 16):

For Swift 3,

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
```

and add `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by simply **overriding** `prefersStatusBarHidden` property in your ViewController as shown below :

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
   return true
}
```

[image: Screenshot added]

This works for Swift 3/4.

Comment: Its not working for pushed view controller.

Answer (score 4):

Hide Status Bar smoothly by just using UIAnimation and stored property.

**Swift 3+**

```
  var statusBarState = false
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return statusBarState
    }
```

And then in viewWillAppear

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        statusBarState = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.30) {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For those still struggling, the below works for iOS9.

You update the rootViewController prefersStatusBarHidden function by calling it from your individual child/grandchild viewControllers. This works where you add childViewControllers directly to your rootViewController.

You don't need to set anything in the info.plist, but setting setting 'statusBarIsInitiallyHidden' works independently of the below.

First, in your rootViewController, add the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateStatusBarAppearance:) name:@"kStatusBarAppearance" object:nil]; 
}
-(void)updateStatusBarAppearance:(NSNotification *)n {
    statusBarIsHidden = [n.object boolValue];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; //optional
}
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return statusBarIsHidden;
}
```

Then, in the single view controller where you want to hide the status bar, call this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kStatusBarAppearance" object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]];
}
-(void)popSelf {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kStatusBarAppearance" object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### When all else fails (as it did for me) Swift 4.1

No editing of .plist required. And AppStore will approve it

```
(UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow)?.isHidden = false
```

Answer (score 2):

A late answer but if you need an alternative solution you can use this:

```
public func ShowStatusBar() {

    let statusBarWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        statusBarWindow?.alpha = 1
    }
}

public func HideStatusBar() {

    let statusBarWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        statusBarWindow?.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: StatusBarWindow is no longer available on iOS 13 or newer

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // hide status bar
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
            window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1
        }
    })

}

override public func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Show status bar
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
            window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}
```

if this code doesn't work, you need to add this key in the info.plist

**View controller-based status bar appearance - NO**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode Version 9.2 / Swift 3.2 / iOS 11

I got this answer form [BADCloud](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88817) although I'm not sure why it didn't work for him.

Anyway it worked for me for a specific view controller.

The difference between this answer and the other answers on here is that in my `info.plist` when I initially had *View controller-based status bar appearance - NO* with the 2 statusBar methods below it didn't work but when I changed it to *Yes* is worked with both of them.

In the `info.plist` change:
**View controller-based status bar appearance - YES**
[image]

In the view controller you want it changed in add:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add this in ViewDidLoad
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

// add this underneath ViewDidLoad
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return true
}
```

Comment: You can skip code written in viewDidLoad(). setting flag in info.plist and overriding prefersStatusBarHidden is enough. Nice work bro, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution for iOS 11 and Swift 4, giving you full control from your program.

```
var statusBarHidden : Bool?

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        if let status = statusBarHidden { return status } else { return false }
    }
    set(status) {
        statusBarHidden = status
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

Now you can simply show or hide the status bar by setting the property from your code. I tested it like this:

```
@IBAction func Show(_ sender: Any) {
    prefersStatusBarHidden = false
}

@IBAction func Hide(_ sender: Any) {
    prefersStatusBarHidden = true
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
```

and when you want it back in a separate VC:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .None)
```

Comment: This was deprecated in iOS9. Greg's answer is the correct one.