# Hide status bar failed

Tags: ios, swift

There are two viewcontrollers.

Controller A with status bar.
Controller B without status bar.

When I push A to B, there is still the status bar in B.

To hide the status bar in B. I set below in B.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
```

I have tried to set the prefersStatusBarHidden to true, but it failed.
When I use present, there is no status bar in B.

Do you know the reason why it doesn't work? What's wrong with the codes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/40376263/2776008

Answer (score 0):

override this method in your ViewController B

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

override same method in your ViewController A

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Include this in your plist file.

> View controller-based status bar appearance" flag in Info.plist to YES

Comment: I just run on sample code its works fine. Can you remove other code related to status bar

Comment: Updated ans plz check

Comment: Removed other codes related to status bar, still didn't work.

Comment: Did you added my changes in plist file

Comment: Yeah, I added it.

Comment: Now only i can fix in your code by debugging, because this working perfectly in my side

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help. I will continue to fix it.

Comment: I can check if you can share your project link mshauket.developer@gmail.com